# How can I hide/bypass the Host signing page on Docusign Android SDK implementation?

Tags: android, docusignapi

How can I hide/bypass this Host signing page?
[Host signing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyaC2.png)

I've already tried selecting **"No, I choose not to use an Electronic Record and Signature Disclosure at this time."** on Settings -> Legal Disclosure section in DocuSign web portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to launch signing ceremony.

1. Compose an envelope(composeEnvelope() api):

   1.1 DocuSign.getInstance().getEnvelopeDelegate().composeAndSendEnvelope() creates the envelope from scratch. This approach does not use templates.

   1.2 DocuSign.getInstance().getSigningDelegate().sign() launches the signing ceremony. It directly launches the signing screen and does not display 'Host signing' page as mentioned in the question.
2. Using template(useTemplate() api):

   2.1 DocuSign.getInstance().getTemplateDelegate().useTemplate() uses the template based on the cached template. But, in this approach it launches the 'Host signing' page as mentioned in the question. If you want to skip that Host singing page while using templates, it is a new requirement and please create a new issue explaining about the requirement in https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk/issues

Comment: ok, I'm using DocuSign.getInstance().getTemplateDelegate().useTemplate(), so I will create a new issue explaining the requirement. thanks

Comment: here is the new issue: https://github.com/docusign/mobile-android-sdk/issues/4